# Google Search: blank screen after a few seconds

Tags: search

Good morning ,
after about 30 sec. having carried out a search on GOOGLE, while I am looking at the results, the page disappears and becomes white. If I hover the mouse the links are detected.
This all happens to me with different browsers, CHROME, OPERA, FIREFOX, while with EDGE there is a brief flash after 30' but then the display remains stable and viewable.
Has anyone had a similar experience?

I made a fix by modifying the code of the search page every time. I'll give the example with OPERA but it applies to all the others.

After showing the results of the page, once it becomes blank, I make the following changes:

- right click and select INSPECT ELEMENT
- in the TAG  search for STYLE
- I replace the term "style" with style="opacity: 1;"
- the page becomes viewable and no longer becomes blank

It seems that the element.style {} element is empty at the beginning and after a fixed time the page goes dark.

Does anyone know of any patches to apply because doing it for every search is such a hassle?